# Есть ли возможность улучшить код для параллельного нахождения комбинаций?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, оптимизация, комбинаторика

Мне необходимо создать алгоритм который будет выдавать комбинации размером в 10 элементов из начального массива данных. Многопоточность реализована передачей общего количества потоков и номера текущего потока, что позволяет перебирать комбинации с пропуском.

Изначальный код взял отсюда: https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/obtaining-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n-in-c/

Он не имел возможности поиска для отдельного потока, поэтому я немного переписал код и попытался максимально его оптимизировать (убрать использование LINQ, списков, указать явное кол-во элементов).
Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

```cs
// Эта функция почти не изменилась, за исключением того что я явно указал один параметр 10 и подставил его везде где он использовался
static public bool NextCombination(int[] num, int n)
{
   bool finished = false;
   bool changed = false;
   for (int i = 9; !finished && !changed; --i)
   {
      if (num[i] < n - 10 + i)
      {
         ++num[i];
         if (i < 9)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j)
               num[j] = num[j - 1] + 1;
         changed = true;
      }
      finished = i == 0;
   }
   return changed;
}

static public IEnumerable Combinations<MyClass>(MyClass[] elem, int start, int skip)
{
   int size = elem.Length;
   int[] numbers = new int[10] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
   long step = 0;
   MyClass[] resultList = new MyClass[10]; // Массив который будет содержать текущую комбинацию

   do
   {
      if ((step - start) % skip == 0) //Если текущая комбинация подходит к номеру текущего потока
      {
         // Сохранить текущую комбинацию в массив и выдать её через yield return. Так оно работает гораздо быстрее, чем через LINQ как это было в оригинальной статье
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            resultList[i] = elem[numbers[i]];
         yield return resultList;
      }
      step++; // Счётчик текущей комбинации
   } while (NextCombination(numbers, size));
}
```

Вызываю я эту функцию таким образом:

```cs
// Это выполняется в каждом отдельном потоке
// pool - массив который может достигать сотни элементов
// start - номер текущего потока (от 0)
// skip - кол-во потоков
public void SearchThread(MyClass[] pool, int start, int skip)
{
   foreach (MyClass[] _ in Combinations(pool, start, skip))
   {
      //Обработка результата
      //Выходной массив должен быть длинной в 10 элементов и не иметь повторов
   }
}


// Код который запускает потоки:
List<Thread> searchThreads = new List<Thread>();
MyClass[] pool = new MyClass[100]; //Массив элементов, из которых будут собираться пары длинной в 10 объектов
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   pool[i] = new MyClass();

int threads = threadCount; //Кол-во потоков которое я получаю с формы
try
{
   for (int j = 0; j < threads; j++) {
      int startIndex = j; //Необходимо скопировать значение в другую переменную, иначе два потока могут получить один айди
      Thread newThread = new Thread(() => SearchThread(pool.ToArray(), wanted, startIndex, threads));
      newThread.Start();
      searchThreads.Add(newThread); //Сохраняю поток в список чтобы его можно было закрыть при завершении работы
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность улучшить код, либо же вовсе переделать его с нуля.

Comment: Что-то не видно в вашем коде потоков, совсем. Как этот код запустить? И количество комбинаций для массива длиной 10 будет небольшим. Я не уверен, что это имеет вообще смысл распараллеливать.

Comment: Последний блок кода запускается в каждом потоке через Thread. 10 это длина выходного массива. Вводные данные могут иметь длину до сотни элементов, что на выходе даёт около 17 триллионов вариантов

Comment: Покажите полный код. В противном случае нет возможности его протестировать. И было бы неплохо увидеть пример входных данных и ожидаемый результат для наглядности.

Comment: В текущей реализации метод `Combinations` не является потокобезопасным. Переменная `step` инкрементируется без лока. Массив `resultList` используется один и тот же для всех потоков.